# How to switch between views using the finger touch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I made an application to navigate between views. Each view contains Different text. The navigation is done by button. But I want to replace that by the finger touch (slide right or left). I mean, becomes a movement between the views using touch by finger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). See [this tutorial](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/5/4/ipad-gestures.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.DarkDust. I am grateful to you

Answer (score 1):

You can add swip gesture on the view or you can also implement touch delegates like

```
 – touchesMoved:withEvent:
    – touchesEnded:withEvent:
    – touchesCancelled:withEvent:
```

to implement your requirement

Comment: these are no delegates method.